# DNS name vs MachineName/Localhost for VS Add Service References

Tags: wcf

We are developing a Silverlight 3 application using WCF services on the back-end. Some of these services will also be consumed by external clients. We'll be using IIS to host these services.

I've noticed that when using VS to add a Service Reference it uses the machine name to resolve the WSDL location and schemaLocations in the XSD's.  If we specify localhost in the endpoint address in the web.config, VS uses localhost. However this breaks the IIS hosting as IIS uses the address relative to where the service is hosted.  So I was wondering what I can do to make the WSDL's refer to a DNS name and not a machine name?  Do I need to generate the WSDL's and proxies outside of VS?

Thanks